# Connecting Sony SmartEyeGlasses with Desktop

Tags: sony, sony-smarteyeglass

Is there a way to connect Sony SmartEyeGlasses directly with a PC using bluetooth?

I have to create a Augmented Reality application which cannot use Android Phone or any phone because the application will be used  but I want to use Sony SmartEyeGlasses to create this AR application.

I know It uses Android as Base platform . So I was thinking of installing android on Desktop pc like REMIX OS or something else.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a direct way to connect SmartEyeglass to PC using bluetooth.

But as you described, a virtual machine running Android may work. You will need to install SmartConnect and SmartEyeglass apps onto virtual machine. Please make sure bluetooth also works in the virtual machine.